# Condition is true if only 1 out of 3 variables is true or if the 3 are false: better logic?

Tags: logic

I have this condition:

**(A is true OR B is true OR C is true) OR (A is false AND B is false AND C is false)**

*(edit: It's been pointed out that this formula is wrong for what I want)*

So as the title says, I want the condition to be true if only 1 of A, B or C is true, or if they're all false.

Is there a better way to write this condition?

edit 2: The context is a SQL Server validation check.

Thanks.

Comment: Your notation is wrong tho because this includes when A is true and B is true and C is false , B is true and C is true and A is false , C is true and A is true and B is false , A is true and B is true and C is true .

Comment: @aryan Indeed. I've been well inspired to come ask this question here :) Forget the condition's formula then, what I asked for afterwards is what I want.

Comment: What are the operators i can use ??Or you are ok with any operators ??

Comment: WA gives [some forms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+and+not+B+and+not+C%29+or+%28not+A+and+B+and+not+C%29+or+%28not+A+and+not+B+and+C%29+or+%28not+A+and+not+B+and+not+C%29), maybe you'll like some of them. @Kilazur

Comment: @aryan it's for some SQL Server check, so not many operators available. Equal, Different than, parenthesis basically. Alexey thanks, I checked it out, that's basically what I was going to write in the end, I hoped for something simpler, but maybe it's impossible here

Comment: `A+B+C<=1` or something similar should work for an SQL after conversion bool to int, even explicit, like `IF(A,1,0)+IF(B,1,0)+IF(B,1,0)<=1`. So please try to *always* include all related context into the question, knowing you're making an SQL query helps much here)

Comment: @Alexey simple and smart, I think that's the way to go. Please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an SQL query something similar to `A+B+C<=1` should work with implicit conversion from `bool` to `int`, although the SQL dialect isn't mentioned in the OP I can assume this `IF(A,1,0)+IF(B,1,0)+IF(C,1,0)<=1` shuold work either way, because most SQL dialects have `IF`, if do not support implicit bool$\to$int conversion.

Comment: Worked for me, a simple addition does the trick. I did have to convert my BIT to INT, but that's trivial and outside the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you want is

```
(A true AND B false AND C false)     // only A true
OR
(A false AND B true AND C false)     // only B true
OR
(A false AND B false AND C true)     // only C true  
OR
(A false AND B false AND C false)    // none true
```

In conventional propositional logic notation:

$
\underbrace{(A \land \neg B \land \neg C)}_{\text{only $A$ true}} \lor 
\underbrace{(\neg A \land B \land \neg C)}_{\text{only $B$ true}} \lor 
\underbrace{(\neg A \land \neg B \land C)}_{\text{only $C$ true}} \lor
\underbrace{(\neg A \land \neg B \land \neg C)}_{\text{none true}}  
$.